# How to check if a string has a more than n repetitive patterns in GO?

Tags: go

I want to check if a string contains repetitive patterns above a threshold .

For example, these two strings both exceed a threshold of 2:

```
"xyzxyzxyz" // contains "xyz" 3 times in succession
"abxyxyxyns" //  contains "xy" 3 times in succession
```

Does anyone know how this is possible?

Comment: I have restructured your question a little, to make it clearer what you are asking. If you feel you can improve it further, please [edit] the question - users on this site are encouraged to re-edit their questions to improve them as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "repetitions" modifier.

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`(xy){3,}`)      // match "xy" 3 or more times
fmt.Println(re.MatchString("abxyxyns"))   // false
fmt.Println(re.MatchString("abxyxyxyns")) // true
```

The available options for the regpexp package's RE2 implementation are documented here:

https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax